# requests cookiejar - send multiple cookies from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, cookiejar

I'm hoping someone can help me with creating a cookie jar with multiple cookies from a list of dictionaries. This is in python3.

I've tried a few different methods, but they either overwrite the previous cookie or don't accept non-standard cookie attribs (such as httpOnly)

The cookies are returned from Flaresolverr (which I believe is the same output as selenium) as multiple dictionaries in a list, e.g.:

```
cookies = [
      {
        "name": "ASP.NET_SessionId",
        "value": "SOMEVALUE",
        "domain": "sub.mydomain.co.uk",
        "path": "/",
        "expires": -1,
        "size": 41,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "secure": false,
        "session": true
      },
      {
        "name": "__cfduid",
        "value": "SOMEVALUE",
        "domain": ".mydomain.co.uk",
        "path": "/",
        "expires": 1622898293.967355,
        "size": 51,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "secure": true,
        "session": false,
        "sameSite": "Lax"
      }
   ]
```

So if I then try to add them all in a cookie jar, you can see "`__cfduid`" is the only cookie in the jar:

```
r = requests.session()
for c in cookies:
      r.cookies.update(c)

print(r.cookies)
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie domain=.mydomain.co.uk for />, <Cookie expires=1622898293.967355 for />, <Cookie httpOnly=True for />, <Cookie name=__cfduid for />, <Cookie path=/ for />, <Cookie sameSite=Lax for />, <Cookie secure=True for />, <Cookie session=False for />, <Cookie size=51 for />, <Cookie value=SOMEVALUE for />]>
```

I've also tried `jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()` and `jar.set(xxxx)` but it doesn't like non-standard cookie attributes (e.g. httpOnly)

I can't do a `r= requests.get` and take the cookies from r.cookies because the cookies are returned as a json inside the requests.text (or requests.json), not as part of the session itself.

I've done plenty of searching but I can't find anything that works - any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Nobody has any ideas? :(

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is set(), not update(). It can take all its arguments as keyword arguments, but it must match as documented by [http.cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookie-objects). Also, the session parameter is called discard in a Cookie object. With some list comprehensions, we can convert it to the form it needs:

```
cookie_props = ['name', 'value', 'port', 'domain', 'path', 'expires', 'secure', 'discard']
cookiejar = [dict([(k, item['session' if k == 'discard' else k])
             for k in cookie_props if k in item]) for item in cookies]

r = requests.session()
for c in cookiejar:
    r.cookies.set(**c)
print(r.cookies)
print(len(r.cookies))
```

The list comprehension renames session to discard and only copies over the name/value pairs that match properties accepted by the set() method on [http.cookiejar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookie-objects).